# how to user interface in OO

Tags: oop, database-design

there is a class named as "composite", in which, it stores a list. I want to write a method to calculate the result of the list. where should I wirte the calculation method? Based on the OO methodology, do I need to create an interface of calculation, and make it be implemented by the composite class? If yes, can you explain why?
Thanks.

```
package composite;

public abstract class Component {

private int level;

public abstract void add(Component component);

public abstract void remove(Component component);

public abstract void eachChild();

   public int getLevel() {
      return level;    }

   public void setLevel(int level) {
      this.level = level;    } }



package composite;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Composite extends Component implements ILevelCalculator
{

ArrayList<Component> componentList = new ArrayList<Component>();

@Override public void add(Component component) {   
componentList.add(component); }

@Override public void remove(Component component) {   
componentList.remove(component); }

@Override public void eachChild() {   
System.out.println(this.getLevel() + " excuted...");    for
(Component component : componentList) {
      component.eachChild();    } }

@Override public int getLevel() {    int levelResult;    levelResult
= getTheBiggestNo(componentList);    return levelResult; }

private int getTheBiggestNo(ArrayList<Component> componentList) {   
int theBiggestNo = 0;    if (componentList.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("The list is empty!");    } else {
      theBiggestNo = getCompareResult(componentList);    }    return theBiggestNo; }

private int getCompareResult(ArrayList<Component> componentList) {  
int result = 0;    for (Component biggest : componentList) {
      if (biggest.getLevel() > result) {
         result = biggest.getLevel();
      }    }    return result; } }


package composite;

public interface ILevelCalculator { public int getLevel(); }


package composite;

public class Leaf extends Component {

   @Override    public void add(Component component) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");    }

   @Override    public void remove(Component component) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");    }

   @Override    public void eachChild() {
      System.out.println("Leaf's name:"+this.getLevel());    }

}



package composite;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {    Composite questionnaire
= new Composite();    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      Composite dimension = new Composite();    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
      Leaf question = new Leaf();
      question.setLevel(i);
      dimension.add(question);    }
      questionnaire.add(dimension);
      System.out.println("The dimension < "+i+" > result is: "+questionnaire.getLevel());    }

   System.out.println("The final result is:
"+questionnaire.getLevel()); } }
```

Comment: Try to post some code or make your question at bit more clear, cause right now it's hard to understand what's being told about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds like you have your OO a bit mixed up.  If I had a class called composite it could implement an interface which had a method called calculate. Then by requirement of the interface your class needs a calculate method.  Also, you tagged database-design for this.  Was there something more to your question or was this just a generic OOP question?

Comment: Hi dude, I just attached the code, could you please help? I wanna know wheter it is correct to create the interface?

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  I think you are actually wanting to implement your interface on the component class from the way you have it defined here.  Is composite meant to be used polymorphically?  What's the english version of what you are trying to accomplish?  Business problem?  Sometimes it helps me to define that first, then write the class / interface code.

Comment: Also one last thing here. It's not clear whether you actually need an interface or not at all.  Do you have other classes implementing this interface?  You may not even need the inheritance either if it's just this single class.